# Flask + jinja - how to reference jinja variable by condition

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have a sqlalchemy query do it in server side. and pass the variable back to client side like this:

```
frames      = db.session.query(Frame).filter_by(task_id = task.id)

return render_template('annotate.html', attributes = attributes, \
                frames = frames, task_name = task.task_name, start_frame = start_frame)
```

where the frames contains many frame information I need.Now in the client side I need to reference the frames like this.

```
<img id="label" src="{{url_for('static', filename= 'data/' + task_name + '/' + frames[start_frame].frame_name) }}" class="img-thumbnail">
```

but I want to update the img when i click the next`(start_frame+1)` and previous`(start_frame-1)` button.
[image]

which mean that I have to update the reference of frames`"{{frames[start_frame]}}"` array(jinja variable), how ever i cant do it in javascript function. Is there any approach I can deal with this scenario?

Comment: just to be in the same page, you're fetching that info from the database before you render the page? and you want to use those values to create some images dynamically... is that right?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to achieve what you need.

I tried to explain two of them, one of which uses `AJAX` and a separate view for image path, and the other handles all the data on the client side.

Both options have their own pros and cons. So, you can decide based on your own preference.

**OPTION I**

Create a view on the server side that returns the `<img>` with the proper `src` for a given `frame_number` parameter.
Then, on the client side, you can request that view via the current frame_number, and update the `<img>` when

- the page loaded for the first time
- prev/next buttons pressed

An example of this new view for AJAX requests would be

```
@app.route('/image')
def image():
    task_name = request.args.get('task_name')

    try:
        frame_number = int(request.args.get('frame_number'))
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        frame_number = 1

    # this line is just for example
    # run your query to get frame_name
    frame_name = str(frame_number) + '.png'

    return render_template('image.html', task_name=task_name, frame_name=frame_name)
```

And, this would be your `image.html`. It just contains the `img` tag that you use in `annotate.html`

```
<img id="label" src="{{url_for('static', filename= 'data/' + task_name + '/' + frame_name) }}" class="img-thumbnail" width="64" height="64" />
```

Finally, in your `annotate.html`, having a function to load the image

```
function loadImage() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ url_for('image') }}",
        type: "get",
        data: { 
            task_name: "{{ task_name }}",
            frame_number: $("image").attr("frame-number")
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $("#image").html(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            $("#image").html("an error occured");
        }
    });
}
```

Probably, the tricky part is to store the current `frame_number`. I recommend to store it as an **html attribute** in a **html element** (preferably, where you display your image.)

```
<div id="image" frame-number="{{ frame_number }}"></div>
```

So, in prev/next buttons click action, you can update the same attribute and call `loadImage()` again.

I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/yasinyildiza/b8abcb973bd8e08c0312c5694486b016) for a full example.

**OPTION II**

In this option, you don't need to create an additional view to provide the current image. Instead, we store all the data on the client (again in html attributes, but other ways are possible for this storage). And, by a similar pagination implementation in option I, we will be able to select the right frame_name to construct the image path.

I put important parts of this implementation, and for details you can check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/yasinyildiza/905415bc975fea0bfa7a5cb3ee16ac36).

```
<!-- here, you can store all the frame names on the client side -->
<!-- notice that 'frames' parameter from view function is no longer available on the client side on you render it -->
<!-- so, this way is kind of a transformation of that information to make it possible to store on the client side -->
{% for frame in frames %}
    <div id="frame-name-{{ loop.index }}" name="{{ frame.frame_name }}" hidden="hidden"></div>
{% endfor %}

function getFrameName() {
    return $("#frame-name-" + getFrameNumber()).attr("name");
}

function loadImage() {
    $("#image").attr("src", "/static/data/" + getTaskName() + "/" + getFrameName());
    $("#current").html(getFrameNumber());
}
```